# What happens when a user is caught doing robo-reviews?

Tags: support, review-suspension, review-abuse

I think I read somewhere that users who don't review well are banned for 1 week from reviewing tasks. Seems like a pretty lame punishment, so I'm wondering the following:

- After the week ban, are they free again to just continue doing it?
- Do they get to keep the review badges they got?
- What happens to repeat offenders?
- Do users who are caught get watched more closely in future or do they need to be caught again with the same probability?

Comment: Personally I've always thought that resetting the user's review count to `0` would be a good idea.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256231/review-ban-progressive-system?rq=1

Comment: @Sam: For those who did robo on all reviews, yes. For those who get banned because they made a few mistakes in audits, depends on the situation.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I agree, although users do need to have the added incentive to not race through reviews just to get badges. We have a "Skip" button for a reason.

Comment: @Sam: That is true. I have no problem resetting to 0 for robo's, but how do we distinguish them?

Comment: @Sam - I think that might end up being counter productive. They'd just start again.

Comment: @PatrickHofman We can't (well not accurately). One of the main differences between a genuine user that fails an audit and a robo-reviewer would be the genuine user's incentive to review properly, we all make mistakes (and learn from them, except robo's) so genuine users should see where they went wrong correct their methodology, slow down, and move on. Well that's *my* (non-expert) interpretation of the subject.

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, but unless they change their reviewing strategy they'll only keep getting reset back to `0` and never get their precious badge(s).

Comment: @Sam the point is they will keep trying.  If they are only badge hunting, they will stop at 1000.  If you keep resetting, they will do far more damage because they will end up reviewing far more than 1000 posts

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yeah I guess that would be worse. Shame we can't just have an simple algorithm for detecting robo-reviewers, darn human diversity (lol).

Comment: @psubsee2003 What about letting `[skip]` increment the review counter so that robo-reviewers could stick to that option, get their coveted badge yet not negatively impact the system? It would restore the actual decision making activities to real reviewers who try to make informed decisions.