# Can you find out all of your failed review audits?

Tags: support, review-audits

Today I was given a 7 day review ban for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5643783) audit, which was a misclick, but that's not the point, we all make mistakes! A few weeks ago I was given a 3 day ban for an audit which I agree I made the wrong choice.

So I was wondering, is there a way to see all of your failed review audits? I had several review audit failures when I started reviewing, but at that time I didn't realise they would result in bans, so I didn't pay enough attention to them, therefore I would like to see what I failed on.

Secondly, is there a general process for banning? As when I have searched for this topic, I find people mentioning a wide range of delay times and time periods.

Comment: [another one from SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192899/how-many-review-audits-did-i-fail)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot see *just* failed audits, no. You can see your entire review history by going to the *history* tab for any review queue, and you'd have to click through those to see which ones were review audits.

If you have 10k+ reputation, you get to see *all* reviews on that tab, and you need to click the *my review history* link to the right of the pager (bottom right) to see just your own reviews.

For the Low Quality Review queue that'd be https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history?userId=1558155 for you; that link will work *just for you* or a moderator, even if you don't have 10k+ reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have tried looking through my histories, but can't find the audits without going through each one which would be just a little tedious! Also I have read more related questions on this topic and I see I am not the only one who doesn't know why there isn't a function to review failed audits. I assume next time (hope there won't be one) I will be banned for a month or so?

Comment: @XN16: if you fail another one in the 30 days from the start of your current ban, then yes, you'd get a 30 day ban. See [Review ban progressive system](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256231)

Comment: @RetoKoradi: I did, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Anything about skipped audit reviews ? I failed a few audits recently, so now I skip a lot of reviews when I'm unsure, however I think it could be nice to see if I skipped an audit (to learn). Seems like skipped reviews are not being displayed in the history tab. Do you know if there is any other way ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet: there is also a 'show skipped reviews' checkbox at the bottom of the page. Tick it and skipped posts are included in the history.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Aw thanks, expected such options to be found at the top of the page, not at the bottom. :P

Comment: @MartijnPieters isn't it possible to Query this from the https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: @johnny: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306378/how-to-distinguish-audits-from-real-reviews-in-sede-data

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks,  this will be helpful.  I'm trying to find the last 3/4 of my review bans, My most [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359255/python-match-and-parse-strings-containing-numeric-currency-amounts) ban's have been frustrating because despite the questions being too broad, or requesting documentation for third party libraries.  The community seems to think they are important questions,  in which sometimes they very well maybe, but those exceptions shouldn't be used as review audits.

Comment: @johnny5: I’ve lifted your ban; that was indeed an invalid audit and your recent review track record has been fine otherwise.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hey I know this isn't the right place for this, but if you have some time can you look into another ban I [received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48593687/implementing-a-language-in-haskell-dynamic-typing-for-polymorphic-functions)