# Getting banned from reviewing for each audit fail

Tags: discussion, support, review-suspension

I'm not writing here to cry out my tears but to get explained. I couldn't find the answer to the following question: `Are you getting banned from reviewing for each audit fail?` I got banned from reviewing for a week. Then I returned to reviewing and have reviewed about 100 questions and answers passing 10 audits in two days. Then I have failed one audit and got banned for a month. I know that you have to be careful when reviewing but I wasn't the only one who has marked this question as a duplicate.

What is the algorithm for banning? Are you getting banned for each audit fail or is it that strict just because it was just two-three days after previous ban has ended? Does it mean that if I ever fail again I'll be banned for a year?

I understand that you have to be very careful when reviewing but sometimes audit-questions have `Thanks in advance` or sth like that which is against the `How to ask` as you don't say it to your desk mate when asking about something.

Summarizing;

- Are you getting banned for every audit fail after once being banned?
- Is every next ban longer or is it possible that there will be a day on which I won't be in danger of a year long ban just for one mistake?
- Is time since last ban ended being considered by banning algorithm?
- How many audits have I passed and how many have I failed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After the first review suspension, for the next 30 days *any* failed audit will result in a new suspension. ([Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256234/812149)).

The first review suspension lasts 2 days; the second 7 days; the third 30 days. If you manage to not fail audits for 30 days, it'll start over at 2 again.

A moderator can give you a manual suspension, that is longer - but these suspensions too are capped at a 30 days maximum.

The ban should come with a few examples of things you reviewed wrongly, but you don't get an overview of all your faulty reviews. You'll have to look in your own review history to find them.

But audits are only the worst cases. Don't just try to do the audits right - strive to be a good reviewer. We have a number of posts about how to review.

Regarding questions containing "Thanks in advance", and things like that: these things should be edited out, but they do not make a question bad. A sturdy house can have a broken window. That means it needs a new window, not that the entire house should be demolished. It's the same with Stack Exchange posts - a good post may still need some polishing, but that doesn't make it bad.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I totally believe you but could you please give me some source?

Comment: It doesn't start over for some inexplicable reason. Review bans go back to 2 days when you manage to not get banned for 30 days in a row, and you can't get banned once more **during** a 30-day review ban.

Comment: Unless they recently changed this, a single audit fail will not ban you. It just won't.

Comment: @dorukayhan any source? Again not questioning, just asking.

Comment: @Magisch I'm pretty certain that after the first suspension, a single audit fail will result in a new suspension. But that is not a single audit fail - it is an audit fail on top of the audit fails that caused the first suspension.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I'm pretty sure thats not the case. I haven't been review banned in months, but when I started off I did get hit a couple times. It took always at least failing 2 more audits.

Comment: I believe I got banned for the first time after first or second audit fail.

Comment: @xenteros Then that was probably a manual suspension imposed by a moderator.

Comment: @xenteros http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256234/6304349

Comment: @Magisch It's ambiguous. I'll update it to make it clear.

Comment: @xenteros just to note - there we no moderator imposed review suspensions here... just the normal system cycle of 2->7->30

Comment: @JonClements had never a doubt about that. Are u able to tell me how many audits did I pass and how many failed?

Comment: @xenteros looks like you've got an ~80% pass rate...

Comment: @JonClements Much room for improvement

Answer (score 3):

> I'm not writing here to cry out my tears but to get explained. I couldn't find the answer to the following question: Are you getting banned from reviewing for each audit fail? I got banned from reviewing for a week. Then I returned to reviewing and have reviewed about 100 questions and answers passing 10 audits in two days. Then I have failed one audit and got banned for a month.

Check whether or not you've been manually banned by a moderator first. You can do this by clicking through to the "See this review as an example of what you should have reviewed differently" and if that is not an audit, it was a manual ban.

The algorithm for banning isn't completely known, but its known that it usually takes more then 1 failed audit to ban you. The ban durations go in cycles, and if you've managed to not be banned within a 30 day period, your "cycle" resets:

2 days -> 7 days -> 30 days

After that you'll start with 2 days again.