# Review Queue Fail Time

Tags: discussion

So recently I have gotten a lot of fails on Review Queue audits. I'm struggling to understand exactly how I can improve.

Some of the audits I kinda standby my reasoning for why I chose the certain action.

My question is this. Currently I have one month before I can review any more items. Is there anyway for next time after this ban is up that I can work on and make the time less. Seems like a month for a review ban seems like a really long time.

I understand that this is a community where reviewing is a major task and needs to be taken seriously. I wouldn't say I'm terrible at the audits but defiantly not as good where I need to be. Is there anyway to train for this where I don't get month long bans? Seems like going through the review queues is the best way but it becomes hard when you get month long bans.

Also after that month long ban what is the longest possible review queue ban? Drives me crazy when I fail an audit and I try to take to heart how I failed. But it keeps happening and it's gotten up to a month long ban. Any tips or anything?

Comment: It would be easier to point out your weaknesses if you could link failed review audits in your question.

Comment: @manetsus My most recent for the month ban was this one. http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13329111. REALLY dumb looking back on it. Should have marked it correct.

Comment: @manetsus Felt like it wasn't described as well as it could have been. Seemed to lack detail. Tho maybe my questions have way too much detail that I ask. I guess that doesn't make that question bad. The line between good questions/answers and bad seems very blurred at times and opinion based.

Comment: Keep it in mind that only this review did not led to 1 month ban. It is a consequence of several review audit failed in a short time. Usually system bans for 2 days, then 7 days, then 1 month.

Comment: @manetsus Yeah and seems like good audits don't reset that. Is there anything after 1 month or is 1 month always the longest ban? I guess I'm most concerned about moving forward. I'm bound to fail more down the road.

Comment: Moderators could ban manually for anytime period they want. But longest system review ban most probably 1 month, not sure though.

Comment: I would suggest you to read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing).

Comment: @manetsus Ok that helps. Do you know after this month how I can work to make future bans less time?

Comment: Bargaining for "less time" makes very little sense.  Maybe you ought to conclude that you are just not quite ready yet to review properly.  So take your time, come back in a year or so when you got to know the site better.

Comment: @CharlieFish did you read the notices you received when previously suspended from reviewing - they'd have given you sufficient information to ask earlier about this kind of thing?

Comment: @HansPassant you're getting more cynical every time I see you :)

Comment: @JonClements Yeah. Of course different every time. Guess just need to take more time. Which there was a better way to learn without getting banned every time. Oh well.

Comment: see also: [Review ban progressive system](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256231/review-ban-progressive-system)

Comment: You are asking for tips: start by improving your English. If you think starting a post with "**So** recently" is correct (I consider that bad even in spoken language), and think the same about using slang like 'kinda', you should hit [Skip] for any posts in which you find no problems.

Answer (score 4):

Looking quickly through [your other recent reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/894067/charlie-fish?tab=activity&sort=reviews), you seem to be making the correct decision most of the time on [*obvious* cases](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13329095), so I assume that you have read our guidelines and are attempting to review conscientiously and in good faith. That's good.

However, I notice [the audit you mentioned failing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13329111) was a question tagged the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), yet your profile suggests your primary areas of expertise are [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), and possibly [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone)/[ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). At least, these are the tags for which your contributions have been most well-received. That implies that, either, these are the technologies you know best or, at a minimum, these are the "sections" of Stack Overflow where you are most well-acquainted with the quality standards.

Therefore, my suggestion to you would be to *filter* the items that you review *by tag*. There is a built-in (automated) way of doing this, just click on the "filter" link at the top of the review page and fill in up to three tags:

> [image]

Alternatively, just hit the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button when you see something written in a language/technology that you are not comfortable with.

You say that you felt [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718760/what-does-struct-type1-mean) "wasn't described as well as it could have been," that it "seemed to lack detail." I agree that the question wasn't described as well as it could have been, but that's kind of an unfair standard to hold someone to! The thing you want to look for in the review queues, and *especially* in the "First Posts" queue, is whether a question meets a minimum acceptability threshold. Lots of the things in this queue are going to be unsalvageable crap; those are easy to dispatch. The rest are going to either need some work or be okay. Although this question may not have been perfect, it *was* on-topic, and it *did* contain enough information for someone who understands C to answer it easily, which makes it acceptable. Granted, if you don't know anything about C, it might have looked impossible. Or if you know a lot about C, it might have looked too trivial. The first is dealt with by not reviewing questions on topics you don't understand; the second is dealt with by keeping in mind the purpose of the review queues.

To reiterate—there's no shame in hitting the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button when you are unsure!

Answer (score 2):

To review better, I would suggest you to read this: [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing)

You have to pay more attention while reviewing.

Say, in your [last failed review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/13329111), you might ask for [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But the OP did not ask any coding related problem, rather he asked basically about a conceptual thing which does not require [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Do not worry much about it. People learns through mistakes. Explore on meta more and more and learn from experts.