# Explanation for this Triage

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Can anybody explain why [this triage](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16271464) became O.K.

[image]

Based from my experience, this kind of question should fall in either **Questions asking us to recommend...** flag or **Question seeking debugging help...** flag, mostly in former, because they are asking for an immediate code/answer without them trying first, unless I misunderstood these flags.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend" was never intended for gimme teh codez questions - where did you get the impression that it was?

Comment: In my opinion, its definitely not asking for a software recommendation. It's clear from the tagging that he/she is looking for a way to include this into the eclipse build chain.

Comment: @BoltClock Mine, since it's the closest(for me) flag for that kind of questions. I don't really know what to use, so I use that flag for those questions

Comment: Well, it is at least borderline. This is a typical "I have some requirements and you have to solve it for me" question, but others seem to like that. **Edit**: Oh, it is a Q&A answered by OP himself ... but still, the question doesn't look that good.

Comment: @Tom That's my impression for that triage that's why I clicked **Unsalvageable**. Unfortunately, I failed.

Comment: Asking how something can be done looks perfectly fine for me. Especially when it's about the tool-chain and not about a coding problem.

Comment: @BDL So i guess the reason that I failed is because it is not really a code-feeding question?

Comment: @BoltClock What flag is used for "gimme teh codez" questions?

Comment: For what appears to be a self-answered question, it seems a reasonable (or at least "OK") question to introduce the answer (as a standalone question, it would probably show a lack of research, but if the OP was intending to self-answer, it seems pointless to include/manufacture "I tried this..." parts).

Comment: @TripeHound I agree; I have a feeling that self answered Q/A pairs are pretty hard in general to get right (even though they're encouraged, I guess I'd recommend updating the help center with some rules and warnings). I wouldn't be surprised if most self answered questions are heavily downvoted.

Comment: @Swellar: There *is* no flag for gimme-teh-codez questions in general. They are often, but not always, Too Broad. They are sometimes Unclear. Otherwise, there's basically nothing to do but maybe downvote.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This does **not** "Look okay". It's *way* too broad as a question. How do I get Git information into my C++ EXE file without knowing the Git client, C++ compiler, or Build/CI system is not answerable at all.

It *should* have been closed as "Too Broad". Unfortunately, it got upvoted and picked by an algorithm.

Comment: Will I have some justice for this, or should I accept my fate?

Comment: That's too bad, guess I'll wait until August 2 haha

Comment: Nobody gets a 2 month bann because of one failed audit ;) @Swellar

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt It depends on how long ago the last ban was. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344967/1007939

Comment: @CDspace: If a previous ban is what sends this single failure over the edge, that's still previous failures that are contributing to the ban.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I failed sometimes before because of misunderstood flags too