# Lifting the Review Ban

Tags: discussion, review-audits, triage

Is there a way to lift my ban because of this [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/16271464)?

Looking at it, I'm correct in reviewing it as **Unsalvageable**, yet I was marked as wrong, causing for a review ban *(again)*.  Although I reviewed it before it was closed and edited, in the end I reviewed it right.

And if not possible or if I was really wrong, can the audit provide the explanation as to why I failed? I was shocked when I failed it, and the audit didn't provide any explanation so that I can learn to review better.

**UPDATE**

The ban had been lifted thanks to [Jon Clements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements), and I learned some things about the audits thanks to the people commented here.

Comment: Are you often coming up against bans?

Comment: @CalvT븃 It's just his second time: [Explanation for this triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349908/explanation-for-this-triage),

Comment: Normally I wouldn't mind if I am really wrong, but based from that audit and from some comments and the answer in my previous post, I was supposed to be right, or at least how the audit defined the triage is wrong

Comment: I don't understand how exactly you failed this audit. Because 'Unsalvageable' flags a question for closure ...

Comment: Because on 2017-05-30 (before the audit), [the score of the question was +5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44038428/timeline).

Comment: @Glorfindel It was quite a shock for me when I learned it was an audit, and I failed. Made me re-think if the flags' purposes are what they really meant in their descriptions

Comment: @Pang thanks, missed that.

Comment: There is something really, **really** broken with review when a question gets 5 upvotes when it is asked but 8 downvotes only after two weeks, when it starts get used as an audit.  You'd have to wonder how many of those votes are cast by users that are pissed-off because they failed the audit.  One that *everybody* should pass, given how simple it is to see that the Q+A was highly appreciated by the with 13 helpful votes.  Ugh.

Comment: @HansPassant I guess it is hard for the bot to check the content of the question whether it is good or bad compared to just checking for the current upvotes/downvotes

Comment: So the audit you failed was almost 30 days ago and you are still banned?  How long are you banned for?

Comment: @psubsee2003 In august,forgot the date

Comment: To get a ~3 month ban means you failed an audit within the previous 30 days and that was ~ 6 weeks long or you had a 6 month ban that ended more than 30 days before your last failure.  Not saying it means you deserved this ban - just pointing it out that you do appear to have a significant history of failing audits

Comment: @psubsee2003 this is my longest thus far. It is true that I failed before, but this time my review is correct and it still failed. For me it's a little disheartening

Comment: @Swellar review bans are progressive.  If you keep getting banned within 30 days of your previous ban, you will keep getting longer bans.  I get that it is disheartening, but it is necessary because poor reviews can have a negative impact to the site.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338524/is-there-now-a-two-month-review-ban-period/338526#338526

Comment: @Sweller it appears you're on a 64 day ban that ends on 2nd Aug...

Comment: @psubsee2003 I accepted my previous errors because I realized the mistake,but this time it is not,that's what is disheartening

Comment: @JonClements I don't know how to check my due in mobile,but I guess I am

Comment: *You'd have to wonder how many of those votes are cast by users that are pissed-off because they failed the audit.* @HansPassant I thought that getting just one down vote was enough to disqualify a question from being used as an audit. Is that not automatic?

Comment: Damn dude, how on earth did you manage to get screwed by two different types of audits on the _same question_? That sucks. I really hope they roll back the ban for you!

Comment: @Clonkex What do you mean by two different audit? If you mean my other post about the same audit, it is just the same haha. I was asking there the reason why I failed, this time I am trying if I can lift the ban because of that very same audit

Comment: @Swellar Oh true I am just blind :facepalm: Well I hope they lift the ban anyway, that's a crappy audit. I'm at work and it's friday afternoon, I'm allowed to be a bit dumb :P

Comment: @Swellar I've lifted the ban. Don't forget that if in doubt you can always skip.

Comment: @JonClements Will take note of that, thank you very much. Should I delete this post?

Comment: @Swellar no particular need to do so but ultimately up to you.

Comment: @HansPassant: Definition of "too broad" is very fragile and may change person to person depending on the skills he is expert in. Reviews should be designed considering not all users will be expert in all technologies. Otherwise, review engine should only allow to review the post if user is active in the tags mentioned.

Comment: @psubsee2003 If the user was unfortunatelly banned due to stupid audit and the ban was taken off manually next audit fail is for longer automatically, so it's enough that he was manually banned by mod once for 7 days, then he got unfair 30 and unfair 90. Simple as that.

Comment: @xenteros Is it possible for other users with X number of rep to see the ban history of others?

Comment: @Swellar I don't know

Comment: @Swellar no - that's a diamond only privilege. (Users can't even see if you're currently review banned)

Comment: @JonClements I see, thank you for the info

Comment: @xenteros no moderator has ever been involved in a manual ban here...

Answer (score 6):

There is one another concern with this. Not all users those are reviewing the question you tagged in your post will be able to review it correctly (correct according to Stack Overflow engine/bot). With "not all" I mean the one who do not have even basic knowledge of technology. I read that question just now and I am not sure if it is "too broad" even after looking at "closed as too broad by........" note at bottom.

In fact, I see this as good question qualifying for up-vote. Question at this moment have 11 down-votes and 10 up-votes. One up-vote is from myself. This means around 50 percent users think that this question is good at least till now. I do not know how meta effect will take it on.

[image: Up-votes]

I am banned multiple times for incorrectly reviewing such questions. Only workaround is to skip the question that you do not understand. But in that way, I have to skip at least half of the questions I review. Reverse has also happened to me. I found a question (from my technology) too broad and I reviewed accordingly and got banned saying this is good question that even qualifies for up-vote.

Apart from review, I can find many questions (from my technology) those are clearly too broad and are not closed and have good count of up-votes and very good answers those are up-voted again.

Definition of "too broad" is very fragile and may change person to person depending on the skills he is expert in.

Reviews should be designed considering not all users will be expert in all technologies. Review engine should only allow to review the post if reviewing-user is active in the tags mentioned. This will help improving accuracy.

**Better wording for last paragraph by "@John Slegers" in comments:**

> The questions one is able to review should be based on one's score for at least one of the tags of a question. That would at least prevent people from reviewing questions that don't match their expertise.

Comment: *"I have to skip at least half of the questions I review"* - do it please. Skip questions you do not *fully* understand, vote as unclear if you can't understand, downvote if it's spelled too poorly, ask in comments, etc.

Comment: IMO, the questions one is able to review should be based on one's score for at least one of the tags of a question. That would at least prevent people from reviewing questions that don't match their expertise! Then again, there's so many things about SO that don't really make any sense and that often could be improved a lot by the smallest of changes. Common sense has become a rare commodity these days, it seems... no matter where you go ;-)

Comment: @JohnSlegers: That exactly what I mean. I used your comment in my answer as it explains better. I mentioned your name as well. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: @AmitJoshi : My comment itself is already visible to everyone and it's not exactly anonymous. So, no, I don't mind you referencing my comment along with my name. In fact, I do feel kinda honored ;-)

Comment: @JohnSlegers There are reviews that don't require expertise - it's not difficult to see if something's deliberately vandalised or otherwise just useless and will go nowhere no matter how much we try to help the OP. You mention "common sense" - so, put simply the *onus* to use that is placed on the reviewer - if you don't know what it's about or can't make your mind up - *skip it*.

Comment: @JonClements : Of course, skipping a review is what you SHOULD do if you don't have the right expertise. However, many people don't do that if you don't enforce it. I can't count the times I've seen people review or comment on questions that really have no business reviewing / commenting on because they CLEARLY are lacking the expertise to make any such comments.

Comment: @JohnSlegers curious as to what you mean by *if you don't enforce it*?

Comment: @JonClements : SO has all sorts of restrictions that don't make any sense, like not allowing you to place a bounty or accepting your own answer to your own question during the first two days or the ridiculous restrictions on suggesting tag synonyms. Yet, the perfectly useful practice of enforcing people to only review questions or answers that match their expertise (based on a question's tags & a user's score for that tag) is somehow a bad idea? Really?!

Comment: If you look at the initial wording of the question, it was pretty broad.  It wasn't totally clear from that wording that the question was really about getting a version-control revision string into the source at build-time (without having it literally part of the version-controlled source), specifically for the Eclipse build system.  Maybe people thought the question was also asking how to print the string.  I left some comments with improvement suggestions for the OP on the original question.