# Isn't this question about problems with new Apple sample code too broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, disputed-review-audits

While reviewing the question linked below in Triage, I have marked it as **unsalvageable (too broad)**.

[Displaying a dae file with ARKit and tracking an anchor in the scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402389/arkit-example-swift)

But the queue says **Stop, Look, and Listen- this was an audit**. I know this question is very helpful but **isn't it too broad?**

Comment: It definitely is asking more than one question... That makes it seem broad.

Comment: The usual "known good audit". It's only as good as the people voting on questions on main :|

Comment: **"_Too broad_"** wasn't an unfair assessment; it was **"_unsalvageable (too broad)_"** that was demonstrably untrue.

Comment: Review audits are completely broken this week too. Who would have thought...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351503/5779732

Comment: @AmitJoshi I've read that. I am also banned for four days because of this review.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question did seem a bit all over the place in its [original state](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44402389/3). But really, the first question

> Can someone else run this code and post a screen shot so I can get some satisfaction?

is superfluous and easily edited out without harming the integrity of the question, and the numbering is misleading — the asker really has just one problem to solve, and that's

> - Choose an anchor point to display it
> - Track that anchor point
> - Actually display the .dae file

which by itself is a three-step process that's hardly broad enough that it requires an entire multi-page tutorial, as demonstrated by rickster in their answer (unless *Apple* would like to prove me otherwise).

So while the question wasn't the best in its original state, I disagree that it was unsalvageable by anyone other than the asker. At best, it would've greatly benefited from substantial improvements by a competent editor, and at least one user *did* pass this same audit with a Requires Editing decision.

In fact, now that Josh Caswell has given the question a much-needed cleanup (check out that title edit!), I think it's good to go. Needless to say, at least one more close vote has been cast since Josh's edit, and I fully expect someone else to cast the final vote upon seeing the 4 votes that are already there, so feel free to use your reopen votes if you agree that the question is better the way it is now.

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks and next time I have to read twice carefully.

Comment: @Blasanka: While the idea of triage is to move quickly, the audits are mostly there to train you to be more precise. My advice: don't spend too much time on a single triage item, but be sure to see if a question can be rescued by other editors without a complete redo - if so, Requires Editing is probably the better choice than Unsalvageable. There are tons of crap questions out there of course, but don't overlook the pearls in the sand.