# How did I get suspended from reviewing for this long?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

I failed a review audit (again) and I got suspended for three months. Why? I thought that you could only get suspended for a maximum of thirty days - yet this came up. Why?

[image]

If this is a bug, could I get suspended for a shorter amount of time?

This is not a duplicate. I want to ask ***how*** and ***why*** I got suspended for this long. Was it a moderator decision, or was it the proximity of the audit to the last time I failed?

Comment: See also: [*Review bans should escalate beyond 30 days*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275736/242059) (Meta.SE)

Comment: Quoting [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256234/7795130): "However, if you continue to walk into review bans even after a 30 day ban, don't be surprised if a moderator comes looking. If after your 2, 7 and 30 day bans you still haven't learned, then you'll be on the receiving end of manual bans if needed. -- Martijn Pieters♦" Have you already been banned a few times? Because I think manual bans can go up to a year.

Comment: In my experience, the length of review bans keeps getting longer, and longer, and longer...

Comment: 64 days isn't a long time. Next one will be 128 days, then 256, etc. You see the pattern if you continue reviewing poorly. No moderator was involved in review banning you btw.

Comment: I don't really know quite how to put this, but if you thought [that suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21620785) was a real and acceptable edit, then you should _absolutely not_ be allowed to approve suggested edits.

Comment: Have you considered, at this point, maybe there isn’t anything in reviewing for you? The badges are meaningless, of course (I mean that in the most literal sense), and if you keep getting banned for reviews the site doesn’t want, you’re not helping the site either. Don’t worry about how long the review ban is, just leave reviews behind you altogether.

Comment: See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180032) to get better at reviewing and hopefully avoid future bans.

Comment: Any time if you fail an audit, take a break and don't review for a week. Audit fail is not very bad, the very bad is if you get suspended (even for 2 days). But if you don't review, maybe a week long, you won't get a ban after your next fail. I don't know how long is this time.

Comment: Is there any easter eggs when reaching 1024 or 2048?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You were given an automated review ban for failing three review audits within the past 7 days:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/21599053
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/21599068
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21620785

The system takes into account the previous review ban, and if it was recent (ended within the last 30 days), the new review ban duration will double (*[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287296)*). As your last review ban was 32 days, this time the system increased it to 64 days. There is no upper limit to the duration IIRC (*you can be banned longer than a lifetime*).

Even if you weren't caught by the review audit system, [today](https://reports.sobotics.org/r/zoY4dx) I would have granted you a manual review ban with the same duration (duration following the same rules as failing review audits) for the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21611327
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21610198
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21608825

I recommend taking this time off the review queues to review these reviews I linked above, and consider how choosing a different action would help achieve a helpful outcome.

Comment: So essentially what you're saying is that as soon as I fail an audit, I should stop reviewing for at least a week? Thanks! I wish someone had told me earlier :(

Comment: Reviewing appropriately is more important than trying to cool-off from audits without knowing what you did wrong.

Comment: If someone just gained [Edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) while he is banned he still can't review. What do you think about feature suggestion making an exception or a bonus it this scenario by lifting the review ban? at least for suggested edit queue only. [personal opinion in a related comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275736/review-bans-should-escalate-beyond-30-days/287296#comment1195067_287296).

Comment: @Cfun feel free to create a feature request yourself