# Why did I not pass the audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I Low Quality Post review I got an answer to the question [How to resize image before uploading to CDN using CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835109/how-to-resize-image-before-uploading-to-cdn-using-curl)
. I answered this looks ok: [image]

I don't understand why. I got banned till the end of december...

Comment: If you look at the user profile, it says "CEO at Piio". It was spam (see bottom of the image: "deleted as spam or offensive")

Comment: Still don't understand. This is an attempt to answer, right? Affiliation automatically implies spam?

Comment: It was posted without revealing that the user was affiliated, so yes, is spam. It would also be condidered spam if the user posts links to their own products frequently, even with disclosure.

Comment: Ok, so I'm banned for more than 4 months, can anything be done anout it? The case is not obvious...

Comment: See [How not to be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): "However, you _must_ disclose your affiliation in your answers."

Comment: If a post does look ok, but is in the Low Quality review queue and links to a product - that's a red flag.

Comment: Ok, I get it now, thank you

Comment: Actually there is one more question, @ModusTollens. Do you know, how is the ban time calculated? I did get banned already, but not throughout the last month.

Comment: your current (7th) review ban is 128 days, because you have previously hit the 2,4,8,16,32,64 durations. I recommend if you fail any review audit in future, stop reviewing for 30 days.

Comment: @Andronicus There is some information about ban time in this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256231/1288408

Comment: Alright, I get it now. Thank you guys!

Comment: On the first spot I've thought that I failed an audit :-) :-) :-)

Comment: @SamuelLiew I'm part of the minority here, but I'd actually recommend clicking "Looks OK" on spam (and then later flagging it as spam), because of the way that the system handles review deletions: if the post gets deleted in review, the author will have the ability to undelete it and restore the spam without leaving any trace, and a "Looks OK" review will help reduce the chances of that happening. On my main site (Meta.SE), I've had multiple spam posts deleted in review that I've later had to flag and ask for the review deletion to be changed to a spam deletion so the author can't undelete.

Comment: @gparyani that's wrong. Please vote to delete from review. If the post author undeletes mods will get an auto flag, and we can take corrective action.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Some of these spammers are exploiting another loophole: re-deleting clears said automatic flag, so they undelete and re-delete, and then at some unknown point later, undelete again. This won't solve that problem.

Comment: @gparyani if you see this happening please custom flag.. we can delete accounts