# What determines duration of review suspension?

Tags: support, review-suspension

In the triage queue, I have marked a question as "Requires Editing", while three other reviewers marked it as "Unsalvageable". Apparently because this question is about running a piece of proprietary software and not programming. This wasn't obvious to me and I believe this is the first time my recommendation doesn't match with a consensus, and I appeared to have been banned for 4 months and 5 days.

I am surprised by the length of this suspension, is there a reason why it is so long when most messages from Stack Overflow meta seem to mention a suspension of at most a few days? How is suspension duration determined?

> Your review on triage/25675515 wasn't helpful. The "Requires Editing"
>   option should only be used when other community users (like you) are
>   able to edit/format an already answerable question into a better
>   shape. If a question can be closed or can only be improved/clarified
>   by the question asker, please use the "Unsalvageable" option instead.
>   If in doubt always use the "Skip" option. For more information, see
>   Getting banned from Triage reviews and How does the Triage queue
>   work?.
>
> Come back on Jul 30 at 8:50 to continue reviewing.

Comment: Generally it's about how many times you've previously been banned. If those bans were short enough you may not have noticed them at all. Usually moderators double the previous ban duration each time till you get the message to change your behaviour. You've a history of incorrect reviews basically since you started and you've not learned, since you review multiple posts per day that's a lot of cleanup work you've generated for everyone else.

Comment: Generally, how many review suspensions you received recently, the duration of your last review suspension, but since suspensions can be set at a mod discretion, also the severity and quantity of your badly reviewed posts. For example, the review you were pointed at is a very blatant case where the question was obviously off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 18):

Let's see...

You had multiple review bans for the exact same reason:

> *Your review on [triage review link] wasn't helpful. "Requires Editing" should only be used when other community users (like you) are able to edit/format the question into a better shape. If a question is unsalvagable/unanswerable and/or can only be improved by the author, please flag/vote to close or delete instead. For more information, see [Getting banned from review, although my co-reviewers agree with me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389148).*

- Dec 19 '19
- Feb 16
- Mar 5
- Mar 24

As you did not see or learnt anything from the previous review suspensions, I manually set the duration to be high enough to give you an opportunity to see it since you were practically blowing through multiple reviews with "Requires Editing" incorrectly, including but not limited to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24891727
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25365048
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25527461
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25671585
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25676401
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25675772
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25677481
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25675515
- *[etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8112247/nakx?tab=activity&sort=reviews)*

Also you had a chance to read how to review Triage properly as it's currently featured everywhere for the past two weeks in the sidebar, but unfortunately that didn't catch your attention as well:

[image]

#### How is suspension duration determined?

If manual, at the discretion of moderators. However, moderators rarely go straight to a multi-month ban on the first instance.

Moderators can set a manual duration of up to 365 days, but there is NO limit for  automated bans for failing multiple review audits. For example, the current record for review suspensions is 1024 days, and can double subsequently if [conditions are right](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256231).

#### Why even worry about the length of the suspension?

Unfortunately, improper reviews plays a huge part in creating more work for everyone, [especially when it comes to the Triage queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394498).

Do worry about how to perform reviews properly instead of the length of the review suspension, since the purpose of the review suspension is to allow you to take a break and figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: Alright I missed those, clearly I need to review that. Thanks for taking the time to explain.