# Can duration of first review ban be 2 months?

Tags: support, status-completed, review-queues, review-suspension

I had been reviewing in queues that I have access to. 
First I completed my 40 "First Posts" review. Never knew that would be a surprise test. But I passed them all.

Then I also passed the "Late Answers" reviews.

Review queues may be independent from each other.

I had reviewed 9 TRIAGE posts and it seems I got 4 incorrect. [That's my mistake for understanding "Requires Editing" as the one who asked question should edit it.]

And got this ban from all the review queues.

[image]

The question had a description of what to do but no code of what the guy asking it had tried. Should have been unsalvagable. But I got confused and marked Requires Edit as I thought he can edit the question and add the code. But this option is to be marked when anyone can edit it and make it more useful. So I feel I am mostly incorrect but the issue is of duration.

Actual question is, this is my first review ban [in fact I just crossed 500 rep yesterday].

I checked this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256234/13130697) regarding suspension-duration, and it looks like review suspension durations start from a very less time.

Any specific reason I got a straight 2 months ban? I have no notification in my inbox.

Comment: You probably didn't notice the shorter bans that came before. This is a common problem at the moment, see [Triage needs to be fixed urgently, and users need to be notified upon receiving a review ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394498/1288408)

Comment: @ModusTollens no, as I mentioned. I just crossed 500 rep yesterday and got access to review queues. And passed the other one's. I didn't got any ban earlier.

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait for a moderator then to check what's up in this case.

Comment: Ok, it's barely 24 hours now that I've crossed 500 rep. So that means I didn't received the shorter 2 days, 7 days or even 30 days ban. Let's wait :-)

Comment: People haven't been noticing shorter bans. Moderators also set ban length depending on the amount of mess created that needs cleaning up. If you set off as a novice at 500 miles an hour the police will ban you from driving for longer than if you set off at 35 miles an hour in a 30 limit.

Comment: @RobertLongson you mean my ban is a moderator ban?

Comment: @RobertLongson yeah sure. I'll wait for any confirmation 

Comment: @RobertLongson The question had a description of what to do but no code of what the guy asking it had tried. Should have been unsalvagable. But  I got confused and marked Requires Edit as I thought he can edit the question and add the code. But this option is to be marked when anyone can edit it and make it more useful. So I feel I am mostly incorrect but the issue is of duration :-(

Comment: @Dharmaraj - What about the other three times you made the incorrect choice?  You have explained one of your mistakes.  *This was indeed a moderator ban due to the custom explanation.*

Comment: @Security, quite obviously, as many others before them, they were misled by the "requires editing" label. There is no need to explain each one, if they **now** understand what the button is supposed to mean. If anything, I looking for instances of misused "looks ok" or "no action needed" might be marginally more productive.

Comment: @SecurityHound ok but I didn't received any notification or such before.

Comment: The review suspension is the notification. This is the chance you get to learn to review better. Yes, the system is not awesome, but you can get the most of this opportunity if you want to continue reviewing.

Comment: @yivi ok, but seems there's no way to check who's review was correct cuz in other cases few people have 1 option and others some other option reviewed so dont know who is correct.

Comment: You were not correct in choosing "requires editing" You were suspended to notify you of this, so you could change your approach to reviewing in the future. If you, instead, want to contest that and say that maybe choosing "requires editing" was indeed correct in those cases, you'll have to make a case for it. But considering you admitted you had thought the "requires editing" meant something different that it means, seems like a rather futile endeavour.

Comment: Ok @yivi... going to be long time.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you say you understand your mistake, it's likely a moderator may lift your suspension. But before you go back to reviewing, please read carefully the guide linked as a dupe on this question, and also [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/), which will help you making better decisions on First Posts and Late Answers.

Comment: @yivi I cannot even access First Posts and late posts. Even though I had passed them

Comment: When you are review suspended, you are suspended in all queues. If you are reviewing poorly in one queue, it's likely you are reviewing poorly in other queues as well. And you do not "pass" reviews. You'll continue getting review audits even if your review rights are restored.

Comment: No thanks. Please, take the time to read the linked resources. It will be more useful for you in the long term than additional chatting. If you want to explain anything else, please edit your question.

Comment: @Dharmaraj - I don’t know if you were notified or simply missed it, but it seems you recognize, you selected the incorrect option at least once.  It seems you don’t agree you selected the incorrect option more than once in the triage review queue.

Comment: @SecurityHound i do agree. I made wrong decision twice. And once all three reviewers have different opinions. I felt it could be Editted by user to add details. But as YIVI had said, how do I let a moderator know that I agree and understand my mistake and get the ban lift early?

Comment: @Dharmaraj - If this question was open I would say submit an answer.  Since the question is closed.  Submit a comment that indicates you understand your mistakes.  You can flag that comment for a moderator to review.

Comment: Okay. I understood my mistake and I'll be more careful next while reviewing not only TRIAGE but also first posts and late answers. Though I have successfully passed the later two. Can I request early ban lift? I have read all clarification between `requires edit` and `unsalvagable`. Thanks SecurityHound for suggestion.

Comment: @SecurityHound can't flag my own comment :-(