# What are the current review suspension periods, and how do they escalate?

Tags: support, review-suspension

[This earlier Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256231/review-suspension-progressive-system) says that the intervals for review suspensions are 2 days → 7 days → 30 days, but those intervals seem to be outdated and do not reflect the current practice.

What are the **CURRENT** review suspension time intervals?

Comment: [second top answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344967/839601) in that earlier Q&A provides current intervals, "starting in Nov 2016, a new system was implemented that uses the previous ban duration and the time since that last ban to set your new automatic review ban..."

Answer (score 12):

The automated, system-imposed review suspensions start at 2 days, and then they double each time that a suspension is applied (if within 30 days of the previous suspension; otherwise, the period increases by half of the previous suspension period).

However, moderators can override the system-suggested interval and enter any interval they like when imposing a manual review suspension. If a moderator does this for your first review ban, any subsequent system-imposed review suspensions will use that time period as a starting point.

---

Note that, despite [recent changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351117/plans-for-updates-to-review-queues), the suspension periods haven't really changed. Quoting from [the über-Meta announcement regarding the recent changes to the moderator review suspension tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356377):

> A duration for the suspension must be selected […]. These will default to the escalation rules [that have been in place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287296) for automated audit-based bans since 2016 (start at 2 days, double the previous length whenever a new automatic suspension is started within 30 days of the end of a previous suspension, half the previous length if not).

All that's really changed is the moderator user interface for picking a duration. Instead of:

[image: this]

it now looks like:

[image: old]

Comment: I got an issue with my intervalls and want to resolve it before the 30 days history passed.  I started reviewing when I hit 500 Rep, like approx. 27 days ago. My suspension times were 8 and 16 days. I know my mistakes from [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402737/duration-review-suspension) post, no arguing here. Please have a look why my suspension times differ from your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You were given an 8-day suspension from reviewing on Oct 28th because of decisions you made on the following reviews: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27484850, https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27484206, https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27485377, https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27475890. On Nov 8th, you were automatically suspended for 16 days (double the previous duration) for failing audits. You are now coming out of that 16-day suspension, and will be eligible for reviewing again in 8 hours. Next suspension (if any) will likely be 32 days.