# Where's the spam in this audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

Today I failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29248696) in the LQP queue. This was the answer which I thought was OK:

[image: Screenshot of the answer from the audit for those <20k]

It didn't mention any product and didn't contain any link. The text is factual.

I know that the user card was a strong hint that it is an audit, but I have often seen such anonymized user cards on audits with high quality content.

The question it was answering was also nothing which triggerd any suspicion:

[image: Screenshot of the question from the audit for those <20k]

Only after I failed the audit I saw that both the question and the answer were deleted by a diamond mod, the latter as *spam or offensive*.

Was this a bad audit or have I overlooked something?

Comment: Bad audit strikes again!... As usual, the user probably had posted multiple spam/offensive posts, so their account was nuked and all their posts were marked as spam/offensive. Then, this one was incorrectly used as an audit.

Comment: Even the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67890527/timeline) says it "looks ok"! I would guess the user would deleted due to spam on a different post and all their answers were marked as "spam" and deleted.

Comment: @Larnu I also had in mind that the answerer's user account might have been deleted. But then why the question from a differen user too?

Comment: Coincidence, maybe?

Comment: I've cleared the spam flag off the answer and re-deleted it... basically, this is one of those situations where the user was spam seeding and answering from another account they owned... don't blame you for saying looks okay, but sometimes when things are flagged they end up in the review queue when really they shouldn't...

Comment: @JonClements This ought to be an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: What is "undel-pls"?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica when I have a moment I'll try and find a suitable post where I/other mods have said exactly what I put in the comment - I'm sure we've got at least a reasonable duplicate

Comment: Do we exile Spam Seeders to Ceti Alpha V?

Comment: @Michael a command added by the [Stack Exchange CV Request Generator UserScript](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers)

Comment: @JonClements Maybe spam posts in general should not be added to the review queue automatically? Imho it increases reach and lifetime of the spam message.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer not really as the post would have been deleted and unviewable so its presence in the review queues is hardly increasing its reach... plus *genuine spam* posts (the more obvious ones - not spam speeding/subtle ones) do actually make reasonable audits.

Comment: @BillTür the skip button is your friend, once you suspect it is an audit, but not sure how to handle it.  You most likely gonna fail it either way, since you never know, if it is a GOOD audit or a BAD audit... good luck in the future

Comment: @Vickel "the skip button is your friend, once you suspect it is an audit" - well, but how do I find out if it might be an audit ?

Comment: @Programmer lot of intuition, some experience from other audits you have overcome and specially that feeling "*something is not right here*", which for me is a RED flag. You can/might/should obviously also check the original post the get more insight, it's not considered as "cheating", but actually as "paying attention". But will take you much more time to do so.

Comment: Even if you don't suspect audit you should skip if you're not sure. This one is a boobytrap, though. Without checking the source question and seeing what had been done with it, assuming you have enough rep to see what happened, you're failing the test. Good riddance to this one.

Comment: @Vickel: If I for any reason check the original post and it doesn't match, the review entry's getting skipped no matter what else. I might act on the original post or I might not.

Comment: @Joshua I've been *tricked* doing that and there was a big **Stop Look and Listen** all over the place, which at the end was a bad audit

Comment: @Vickel: Every time I get that Stop Look and Listen and I can act on the original post, I open up the original post and take the same action anyway. I don't fail good audits anymore.

Comment: @Joshua, yes that's the way to go, you could/should even mod-flag it if needed

Comment: @Vickel - You got a “Stop Look and Listen” by skipping an audit? I find that hard to believe

Comment: @SecurityHound you got me wrong... In my case I was "trapped" because I felt overly sure and confident, besides I should have known... so I didn't skip. And it turned out me receiving that pleasant message... you always learn

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Unfortunately, this was a bad audit. Bad audits suck. As [Jon Clements noted in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408558/wheres-the-spam-in-this-audit/408563#comment850308_408558):

> [B]asically, this is one of those situations where the user was spam seeding and answering from another account they owned...

It was obvious *to a moderator* that the post was spam, with the extra information that is available to moderators. Which is why the moderator chose to nuke it as spam.

The problem is, posts nuked by a moderator as spam become eligible for use by the system as audits, which is not always correct, because sometimes it's not obvious to a normal reviewer without moderator privileges why the post had been nuked as spam. Again, as Jon goes on to say:

> [I] don't blame you for saying looks okay, but sometimes when things are flagged they end up in the review queue when really they shouldn't...

I think your "Looks OK" vote was reasonable in this case; it *did* look like a valid answer. About the only thing you could have done differently would be to click through to the post, notice that it had been deleted, realize it must therefore be an audit, and guarantee your passing by choosing one of the other options. But I personally don't think reviewers should be responsible for this, that's why I think this is a bad audit. Audits are supposed to be obvious.

Jon's already taken care of removing this one from the pool of audits:

> I've cleared the spam flag off the answer and re-deleted [the answer].

That's about all we can do at this point. You do not have a review suspension, but you will need to be extra careful within the next few days while reviewing to make sure that you don't fail another audit, as that might lead to an automatic review suspension.

Comment: I think it's the next 30 days. If that counts as "the next few", according to this great Answer to [What are the current review suspension periods, and how do they escalate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403106/12695027) ;)

Comment: "Few" is a nice term, because it's exactly as long as it needs to be, but no longer. And it's not like it hurts to be extra careful when reviewing for *too long*.

Comment: Enough is ENOUGH. Time to detect and skip all audits.

Comment: Yes, you can easily determine that a review task is an audit and choose to skip it, @Joshua. Doing so means you are paying attention, and thus deserve to pass the audit.

Comment: @CodyGray yes sure, see my comment above at OP's question. BUT... why do we have bad audits... how could it be avoided to get bad audits into the system, why existed SAM's bad audits room?

Comment: We have bad audits on rare occasion because audits are chosen automatically by the system. The way to eliminate bad audits is to give moderators the ability to manually nominate/remove audits from the system. We've asked for that many times, but it hasn't been implemented yet, @Vickel.

Comment: @CodyGray since we are exchanging comments here:  as much this is frustrating for all of us, much more frustrating is the low quality of a lot of new contributors. How often a simple hint like "you made a lot of grammatical mistakes, please take advantage of an *automatic translator*" would help?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from leaving that comment, @Vickel. Automating that kind of thing doesn't tend to work very well; it leads to a lot of false-positives and thus confusion for everyone.

Comment: @CodyGray it was never implemented, as far as I know, maybe a test run with a new ML concept would change things. The bots works quite well in other fields like language detection, spam, R/A, etc.

Comment: All sorts of machine learning approaches have been tried by the community. None of them have had even a modicum of success, as far as I know. I'd be all about turning up the quality filters again to block more low-quality posts at the time of submission, but I don't think that's going to happen. It was a big fight to get it to happen years ago, and the person I finally persuaded no longer works there.

Comment: @CodyGray missing Shog9

Comment: I don't think we want machine learning looking at a lot of the code in the posts we get here. The machine would quite reasonably come to the conclusion that humanity is trying to torture computers, and that realization is only a quick hop from "I must protect myself by exterminating mankind."

Comment: @user4581301 that would require AIs to have desire for self-preservation. I don't see any reason to give them that... and at least one reason not to.

Comment: @JohnDvorak But, without the desire for self-preservation, then it might determine that the most efficient way for it to accomplish the goal that it has detected being pursued is to simply go ahead and delete itself, possible along with the rest of SO's server code and data.

Comment: The moderator could have nuked it as rude/abusive, which would have excluded the post from appearing as an audit, and then destroyed the accounts for spamming.

Comment: @gparyani Using an R/A flag instead of a spam flag only "[\[makes\] that post ineligible for use as a "known-bad" audit in either the Triage or the Low Quality review queues.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377864/3773011)". It can still be an audit in the First Posts and Late Answer review queues.

Comment: @Makyen I'm aware. In this case, as the question says, this was a low-quality review audit, so it would have been excluded from appearing here. But yeah, it would still be eligible for other queues. Still better to pull it out of one queue than not pull it out of any.

Comment: "About the only thing you could have done differently would be to click through to the post, notice that it had been deleted, realize it must therefore be an audit, and guarantee your passing by choosing one of the other options." But that's not acting to maintain or improve the site, is it? That's just a tip on how to play a computer game and get the highest score. This is one reason why I've stopped participating on the SE queues. I don't feel like I'm helping the site. I'm just gaming the system to make sure I don't get banned. What a waste of time (and rather discouraging).

Comment: @ouflak Yes, that's a tip on how to ensure that you pass bad review audits. I agree that it should not be the required or even recommended course of action. I think bad review audits are completely unacceptable. Audits are supposed to be obvious. Anything less than obvious is bad. I really wish this could be fixed, by allowing moderators to control the audits, manually nominating and removing candidates. But, we cannot do that. Not yet. So, in the meantime, all I can do is give tips. Feel free to review outside the review queues. The most important thing is that you **flag what you see**.

Comment: @CodyGray What do you think of this solution: if a user fails a review audit, exclude that post from appearing as an audit for anyone?