# Ban for review queue was extended without me doing anything. What is the rule for this case?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-suspension, banning

In December I failed a Suggested Edits audit again. Since I did it before, I was banned until mid-January from reviewing.

Now I wanted to check the exact end-of-ban-date in January and saw that the ban has been extended until March 10th. Please note: I did not do anything in between.

I do not understand the rule here. How are the periods determined? Can somebody please explain?

Please do not misunderstand me, if I did something wrong, it is OK for me to be banned. I simply stop contributing then. No problem.

I would just like to understand the ban extension without me even accessing the review queue? Any rule? Or can moderators do as they please? I did also not receive any message . . .

Comment: Reviews you had made were investigated at a time that happened to be a few hours after your initial suspension. The added edits were plagiarised tag wikis you had approved rather than rejected, and plagiarism is severe enough to warrant an entire separate suspension (largely because the audit suspension you had doesn't compare to plagiarism)

Comment: Suggested edit audits are perhaps the *easiest* to pass. Those don't use auto-selected prior posts that could legitimately be incorrectly selected resulting in bad audits, but are instead generated automatically using Markov chains.

Comment: @gparyani not perhaps; they are. Maybe not in terms of absolute percent (suggested edits is at 94%, tied with a few other queues), but from a detection POV, minimal work is required. And as you've already pointed out, there are no bad suggested edits audits, because they're all generated in a way that makes every single audit a universally bad edit in need of rejection. Barring the occasional misclick (which is exceptionally rare and very recognisable when it happens), failing a suggested edits audit is overwhelmingly a sign of robo-reviewing, and there's generally no way to argue around it

Comment: by blaming the system. Another sign of an otherwise good reviewer misclicking (for any reason; anything from actual accidental clicks to meaning to reject, brainfarting, and hitting the wrong button) is that if it does result in an automated suspension, the other audits are generally always from other queues, and overwhelmingly from queues where bad audit selections run rampant (obviously, there can be other patterns to disprove this as a sign a specific user is a good reviewer, but there's a lot of complications and listing all of them is an exercise in futility)

Answer (score 20):

You seem to have been reviewing rapidly without considering carefully whether or not to approve. For instance your last 20 reviews took 12 minutes and you approved everything.

I believe your review suspension has been extended because of this [poor review approval](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33461001). This replaces a grammatically correct phrase with one that isn't and yet you approved it. When moderators come across such things they often suspend people and if you're already suspended they just increase that existing suspension. It seems that moderators simply didn't catch that until some time after your review.

The default for automatic bans is to double the length of the ban each time unless there's a sufficiently long period where you remain unsuspended. Moderators often do the same but can hand out longer or shorter bans if they wish depending on how serious the issue is that they are encountering. The maximum length of a moderator imposed review suspension is one year though.

Comment: That was indeed a bad review, and did contribute to the decision to extend, but wasn't explicitly listed. The two explicitly listed reviews were https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33423218 and https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33422739 (both of which were approved tag wiki plagiarism). The rest also checks out; patterns of robo reviewing were solidly present, and I believe it was the glide wiki review that made me discover all the problems

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I understand, what I did wrong. No problem. And I will stop contributing. Also no problem. I accept it. But I would be happy, if the question would be answered. What is the rule? I cannot find anything on the help pages. Where is stated how this works. How are periods defined? Or can any mod do what she wants?

Comment: @AM - "I will stop contributing." - You don't need to stop contributing.  You just need to NOT approve edit proposals which shouldn't be approved. "What is the rule?" - One of the rules is NOT approving plagiarized content contained in a tag description. It literally is one of the reasons NOT to approve an edit proposal.

Comment: How do you know it is or is not plagiarized? That can get tricky. If the poster's writing style changed dramatically, that's usually a hint, but you have to A) have and B) inspect other content from the poster. Me, I take a couple lines and paste them into google to see what pops up. After that it's kind-of pray. If I have any suspicions, I slam the skip button.

Comment: Edit reviews of tag wikis are probably one of the more lengthy reviews; doing a good check for plagiarism is *extremely* important and a non-significant of such suggestions *contain* plagiarism. If you're not happy to take that time on them, skip them whenever you encounter them instead, @AM .

Comment: @user4581301: If it looks like it could be on a company's intro product page (look for [weasel words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word#Forms) like "flagship", "advanced", etc.) or its Wikipedia page, it is probably wholesale copied from such a place. Both have near-perfect English and are usually somewhat verbose, and that is unusual for the first revision of a tag wiki.

Comment: “How do you know it is or is not plagiarized?” - **Select text, paste into search engine, if results are shown that contains entire phrases from the tag description it’s plagiarized.** If you are unable to determine if it’s plagiarized or not just skip the review and allow someone willing to trust but verify do the verification work. Verification often takes less than 30 seconds to perform

Comment: I stumbled upon [this tag wiki today](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tendermint/info). The first sentence seems to be wholesale copied from [the GitHub page](https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint) (down to the last comma, dash, and full stop). The last part is less clear. The phrase *"is a decentralized network of independent parallel blockchains"* is used in a lot of places (probably copied from the same source). E.g., [here](https://www.titan.com/research/commentary/2022/09/28/a-closer-look-cosmos-usdatom): *"Cosmos is a decentralized network of independent parallel blockchains, each po"*

Answer (score 5):

[You normally receive a message about your review ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351118/175248) if you click on the drop-down menu taking you to the review queues.  There's usually an accompanying message at the top as well if you're banned.

The rule with review queues is a pretty self-explanatory one, but I don't think it's ever explicitly been spelled out in such a way to say "do X", "don't do Y"...so...

In general, **if you're reviewing something, you're checking the question or answer for *any* fault, and improving *every* fault you can find.**  The revision process **should not *introduce* new faults, and it should not look to add things that are *wholly irrelevant to the post***.

Questions and answers that get reviewed seldom get seen again, just because there's so many questions and answers, and only so many ways they get put into the queue.  There's a lot of impetus on the moderation team to ensure that people who do those kinds of reviews are making reasonably good changes, and there's an unspoken expectation set with reviewers that they're acting in good faith and not passing questions or answers which could have been improved.

Comment: Worth noting that OP has seen both suspension notices (according to the tool anyway), and did so prior to asking

Comment: @Zoe stands with Ukraine. Yes, all clear. The question was: What are the rules for banning periods or extensions? I just read everywhere how shit I am. I know that. But, can somebody kindly answer the question about ban periods and ban period extensions. It is about durations, periods, time spans, or whatever you call that. I am very sorry about my poor English. And, somehow unbelievable how kind people are in answering my question. I do feel really great now . . .

Comment: @AM:  Does that *really* matter?  Use the period of time you've got from the queues to reflect on your last few reviews, what people are doing in terms of reviews here on Meta, and really think about your approach to the reviews.  This [isn't a penalty box where you only have so long to make a Power Play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_play_(sporting_term)#Ice_hockey); you have to really spend the time *away* from the queues and really comprehend what reviewing is meant to accomplish, and realize why your approach was insufficient.

Comment: @AM - “What are the rules for banning periods or extensions?” - Continuous audit failures will result in a suspension, that will slowly increase in length, if additional audits are failed. Additionally, a moderator can based on discovery of a bad edit proposal approval can suspend the privilege entirely based on the users past suspensions.

Comment: @SecurityHound. Thank you. Really. You are the first that tried to answer my question. But I have the suspicion, that there are no written rules, and that it is in the discretion of mods to decide on the length of the penalty. Anyway, no meaning anymore. After this thread, it is clear that I will stop contributing to the review queue from now on . . . . No problem.

Comment: @AM You were not contributing. You were damaging. You are not going to stop doing that, you were stopped from doing that. You are trying to make it seem like you did nothing wrong, pushing you to the worst outcome possible. The idea is that you learn from your mistakes and improve.

Comment: @AM There is no reason to stop contributing as long as you are doing things properly, to rephrase Gimby, it seems like you were just blindly clicking approve on everything. Reviews aren't things to do in record time, you should be taking your time, making sure the suggested content is good content, if you aren't sure, skip it, if it is bad, reject it. I lean more towards rejecting things any as IMO a reject is more valuable than an approve, but that's just me being critical

Comment: @AM:  The advice you're getting is simply "reflect on what you did wrong".  This doesn't feel like reflection; this feels like venting.  Just "stopping" means that you're not taking the time to receive and absorb the feedback that you're getting here.  No one here is calling you out or dragging your name in the mud; we just have *very* exacting standards for the review queues because you're not going to see those questions again, and we want some assurance that someone is going to give them more than a few seconds of time.

Comment: @Makoto - I would argue that not approving plagiarized content isn't exactly a high standard.

Comment: @AM New review bans are twice as long as the previous ban within the past 30 days, after 30 days the ban is cut in half https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403105/what-are-the-current-review-suspension-periods-and-how-do-they-escalate