# What to do when wishing operator help (e.g. review suspended)

Tags: support, review-suspension

I did not get a message, but I realized that I was blocked ("suspended") from reviewing for almost a year, based on three decisions.
As I feel at least two of my decisions are debatable at least, I wonder what I can do.

The two decisions were:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30657989
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30685656

The general help text says each edit should be significant, so just removing one "Thanks" could be non-significant as well.

Most of all, weighing the good decisions against the poorer ones, I still feel the decision is not justified.

In general I'd prefer to be warned first, then maybe be suspended, but not for that long.
Don't get me wrong: I'm not that much eager to do work for free; I rather felt you could need the help I was offering.

Comment: The first review recommendation linked is a critical error because it changed the indentation of a language where indentation is important. Philip Dukhov mentioned this in their review rejection reason.

Comment: As for the first edit, that one made the code formatting *worse* and it didn't even fix the actual code formatting issues that were there. I don't see what's debatable about it.

Comment: What do you mean "operator help"?

Comment: Note that the operators are also people who "do work for free". While it's commendable that you want to help, consider that wrong decisions end up creating *more* work for other volunteers.

Comment: How does removing "Thanks," make the post more confusing or harder to understand?

Comment: *based on three decisions*: Where is the third decision?

Comment: *"I rather felt you could need the help I was offering."* - We always want help... but our help should be helpful, not harmful.

Comment: a year ban, is not only for three false decisions, flag for moderator attention on the reviewed answers and explain that it is excessive. So that another mod can check. Btw. You reviews are really bad

Comment: Who or what is *"operator"* in this context? You? Someone else? Do you mean *"[moderator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderator#Internet)*"? Can you elaborate?

Comment: You were not block for a year from reviewing after only 2 mistakes.  You were suspended more than once, if it was an automatic suspension due to a fail audit, it was several times once where the period was at least 6 months (suspensions based on audits doubled).  To be suspended for a year, you either have been suspended multiple times in the past, or your errors approving an edit caught the eye of a moderator.  I took a look at your reviews, most your decisions, are questionable and left me scratching my head..

Comment: @IanCampbell OK, I must admit that I did not consider this (Personally I never liked the semantic importance of indentation). OK, my fault.

Comment: (BD) I thought two out of three were debatable, so I skipped the third one that probably was my fault. (Nick) Well humans make mistakes, but there should be a difference of making mistakes and deliberately adding nonsense.
  (nbk) I admit: I could skip 90% when I don't feel 100% sure, but I tried to judge when I felt rather sure. Still for the decision only three items were listed.
  (Peter Mortensen) Yes, I meant *moderator*.

Comment: @SecurityHound That's interesting: I *never* got any message that I had been suspended (so I also had no change to find out *why*). Can you elaborate on what exactly made you "scratch your head"?

Comment: @U.Windl - Your review history is extremely questionable, you either are not approving edits that should be approved, or approving only trivial edits that indent code that is already properly formatted. As the moderator pointed out, you have been reviewed suspended, 6 times in the past that means you have more than a handful of failed audits.  I again cannot discount the fact, a moderator doing their job, simply came across your questionable review history and then acted. You had at least a hundred reviews in December 2021, I wouldn’t say that’s, sporadically, when you were active in Nov/Oct

Comment: @SecurityHound "Sporadically" means I might be busy a few days, then pausing for a few weeks. On some days I reviewed the maximum, on other days just a few.

Comment: @U.Windl - Almost 1,000 reviews and 5 suspensions, yet I have had liters thousands, and besides the occasional failed audit, have never been review suspended. The system didn’t use to indicate which reviews were the reason for the suspension, now at least, that part is clear. I don’t buy the explanation that you were unaware you were review suspended, 5 times in the past, when I failed those audits I knew immediately that the system thought I needed a break

Comment: @SecurityHound You don't have to "buy the explanation", but still that's true. Is there any balance between good reviews and bad reviews? An system that considers only one half is inherently broken. Still, as said before, I can live with it, even if I don't understand.

Answer (score 9):

You *do* get warned.

Generally, the system will give you a 2, 7 and finally a 30-day review ban automatically, before flagging your account for moderator attention, which can result in receiving severe (manual) restrictions like these. ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256231/review-suspension-progressive-system))

That said, moderators *can* apply review suspensions outside of that automated system, but it's extremely unlikely you'd get a year out of the blue.

If this truly *was* your first-ever review suspension, I'm sure a moderator would be happy to weigh in.

Comment: They've had 6 total suspensions, including this one, for the record.

Comment: I figured there'd be a history to get a _year_.

Comment: i got  two weeks for some bad reviews at the first time, so 2 days is only for automatic bans

Comment: @nbk correct, I tweaked the answer a bit to clarify.

Comment: @nbk Your first review suspension was 8 days in 2020, and your second one was 4 days in early 2021. Not sure where you got 2 weeks from, but you've not even been suspended for 2 weeks _total_ (... on SO. Can't account for your review suspensions on other sites).

Comment: i didn't get a 2 or 8 days ban, or i missed it, but the two weeks are easy to find as i rarely review anymore, because i dpn't like the system

Comment: So for the records: I *only* noticed that I was suspended when I *actually tried* to review. As I'm reviewing sporadically, I *never* noticed I had been suspended before. I think handling it that way is **very bad**.

Comment: That seems very unlikely... 6 suspensions, that are quite some failed audits... You just happen to stop reviewing the moment you get suspended ___6___ times?

Comment: Anyway: As long as I'm suspended that way, it's very likely that I don't ever know why exactly I was suspended (a few samples were mentioned in the meantime). So it's likely that the same happens again. Don't you see the weakness in the system?

Comment: You can view your review history. Also, every suspension is accompanied with a notification telling you to review your reviews... But considering your unfortunate review history, maybe it's for the best that you ignore that part of the site.

Comment: @Cerbrus Can you show an example how such a "notification" looks like? The only notifications I can remember are those from automated tests ("whether you are paying attention").